# What are the pros and cons of rails page caching vs a 3rd party vendor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku

There are a few 3rd party addons you can add to a Heroku app to manage caching. Why would you use them vs using the built in caching framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming these 3rd party addons work like [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com/) or at least work on the same basic principles.

**Caching Framework**

1. You control when the cache expires, allow for fresher more relavent content.
2. Your site doesn't go down/get messed up/looks fugly when their service goes down.
3. You can permanently cache things that will never change.
4. Can make your own CDN with your own logic and setup.
5. **Fragment caching, meaning only part of the page expires instead of the whole thing, leading to less dog piles.**

**3rd Party Service**

1. Fire and forget.
2. Cheap
3. Usually pull all images, js, and css files into their 'CDN' also.
4. Some claim added security because your site is now basically behind their servers now, though I haven't really read anything that said this was anything but market double talk.

Comment: Might as well roll my own. Thanks!